# Forgot Password Link in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i am trying to implement authentication in rails 2,i know there is no support for devise gem. But can anyone point me in the right direction for implementing authentication and forgot password link in rails 2?Stuck in this for a very long time.

Comment: Why Rails 2, it's seriously outdated.

Comment: @Iceman,i know rails 2 is totally outdated but our company is still stuck in rails 2 version in production...it has go to on...any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I've only used Rails 4. You've probably found this already but will these links help at all? They are Railscasts for creating your own authentication and forgot email functionality.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password